# Is there a difference starting an application by script or by hand in the terminal

Tags: linux, embedded, qt

I have an embedded linux device and a Qt application.

If I start my application in the terminal (with /opt/myApp) then
it runs with good Performance (touch buttons react immediately).

If I let it run at device bootup (started with a script from /opt/etc/init.d) then it runs with slow performance. This means there is a delay from about one second in touch button reaction time.

Is there any difference in starting an application from script or from terminal in Linux that would explain the difference?

Comment: When you execute it as a script, if you wait a few minutes until the system will complete it boot process, do you still face the same slow respond?

Comment: I have put a 20 seconds sleep command in the script. but i still face the same behaviour.

Comment: can you try what I suggested in my previous comment? what happened if you wait a few minutes without touching the device, and then try to touch it?

Comment: After a reboot of the device i waited 5 minutes but had the same slow reaction.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your setup. What distribution are you running? How have you customized it? Does this device use X11? What GUI does it start when booting? Do you set environment variables when you open a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the environment is different.

Running it from init.d it has probably the permission of root, but bron shell you will have other permissions, probably the same as Xorg. Probably there is some missed message between various layers (dbus?) because of different permission, before to go to a compatibility mode.  Try to use crontab with "@boot", so the script will be executed at boot, but as the correct user, and only when all user support are ready.

Comment: So I am on an embedded system and i have only a restricted number of tools installed. Unfortunately crontab isn´t installed. Is there an other possibility to check your suggestion?

Comment: Check the logs. Usually they have some hints. Run your script as the user, e.g. use a launcher in init.d with `su <loginname> -c /your/original/script`